# BitmapFactory.decodeFile restarts the application

Tags: android, dictionary, bitmapfactory

I want to put `images` in a `dictionary`. Total size of images is 22 megabytes. Here is my code.

```
    Dictionary<String, Bitmap> bmpCollection = new Hashtable<String, Bitmap>();
    File filesDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/shared/Lenovo/Resimler/");
    File[] files = filesDirectory.listFiles();
    for (File file:files)
    {
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            String key = file.getName();
            key = key.substring(0,key.length()-4);
            bmpCollection.put(key,bmp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int a = 0;
        }

    }
    return bmpCollection;
```

There is no problem until the 48th file but after that program restart itself when this line work `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());` . It says nothing about error. Do not trigger `catch`. Just restarts the application. What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is out of memory error. Try to decode with purgeable and samplesize bitmap options to optimize memory:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
```